# How to test whether ICCs from different groups are significantly different?

Tags: intraclass-correlation

I need to compare two generalizability (G) coefficients for data that are from two separate populations. G coefficients are a type of intraclass correlation coefficient (ICC).

The literature on statistically comparing G coefficients is sparse by all accounts, so I thought that the best I might do was find out the recommendation for statistically comparing ICCs. I've considered Fisher's Z, but I know ICCs are not normally distributed.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the generalizability coefficients that you obtained involve overlapping measurement methods in the two separate populations (in other words there is non-independence between the two coefficients) you should be able to compare them directly in PROC GLM or MIXED as detailed in this [Book Chapter by Cohen and Doveh (2005)](http://www.emeraldinsight.com/doi/full/10.1016/S1475-9144%2805%2904017-8).

#### Reference

Cohen, A., & Doveh, E. (2005). Significance tests for differences between dependent intraclass correlation coefficients (ICCs). Research in Multi Level Issues, 4, 373-420.

Comment: They are independent. But, I have colleagues that are looking for what to do if they are dependent. Do you have a recommendation for that? Even thought it is an ICC, the data is not hierarchical.